# Model of the QTableView dosent view values as desired

Tags: c++, qt

I have  a QTableview with model. I populate dummy data in the model using this code

```
horizontalHeader.append("Name");
horizontalHeader.append("Type");
horizontalHeader.append("Unit price");
horizontalHeader.append("qty");
item00 = new QStandardItem(QString("0"));
item01 = new QStandardItem(QString("0"));
item02 = new QStandardItem(QString("0"));
item03 = new QStandardItem(QString("0"));
QList<QStandardItem*> list;

list.push_back(item00);
list.push_back(item01);
list.push_back(item02);
list.push_back(item03);

for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
      list.at(0)->setText(QString::number(i));
      list.at(1)->setText(QString::number(i));
      list.at(2)->setText(QString::number(i));
      list.at(3)->setText(QString::number(i));
      model.insertRow(i,list);
}
```

the result should be a table of 100 rows and four columns and the content of the rows is a number but instead I am getting a the first row populated with data and the other rows are just empty as per the following screenshot
[image]

Comment: You probably want `model.insertRow(i, transform(list, [](auto x) { return x->clone(); }));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inserting the same `QStandardItem`s a 100 times, this should result in the following warning for every insert operation, starting from the second:

```
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0xxxxxxxxx
```

So, in your code, all insert operations (starting from the second) will be ignored, and then the `QStandardItem` (that was already inserted in the first operation) is set to the new value of `i` (that explains why you get one row `99`s in it).

Instead, you should use new `QStandardItem`s for each row insert, like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
    QList<QStandardItem*> list;
    list.append(new QStandardItem(QString::number(i)));
    list.append(new QStandardItem(QString::number(i)));
    list.append(new QStandardItem(QString::number(i)));
    list.append(new QStandardItem(QString::number(i)));
    model.insertRow(i,list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the items inside the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    QList<QStandardItem*> list;
    list << new QStandardItem(QString::number(i));
    list << new QStandardItem(QString::number(i));
    list << new QStandardItem(QString::number(i));
    list << new QStandardItem(QString::number(i));

    model.appendRow(list);
}
```

Or even with an inner loop to create the four items.